# Getting a Floating Action button between two layouts which already has elevation

Tags: android, android-layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="65dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="-105dp"
    android:clipChildren="true"
    app:cardElevation="10dp">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/pic"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Raven Starfire"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="155dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Bran, Romania"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall"/>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="#90A4AE"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/bottomTopCard"
    android:elevation="19dp"></LinearLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomTopCard"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top|right"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image]

Well, I need to bring the Floating Action button above the linear layout(lighter shade of ash) at the bottom of the Coordinator Layout.  I set the anchor to top right end of the Linear layout(which works fine), but the FAB seems to have gone below it.
I suppose that the Coordinator layout does not work like the FrameLayout/CardView. Giving elevation doesn't bring the FAB above the Linear layout either.

Any suggestion about bringing the FAB Above that linear layout would be helpful.

Thank you for the answer. The layout turned out like this now,
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the Floating Action button elevation from the app namespace not android:

```
    app:elevation="20dp"
```

not:

```
    android:elevation="20dp"
```

By the way, android material design recommends that the FAB be at 6dp elevation
https://material.google.com/material-design/elevation-shadows.html

Comment: That worked. Thank you.

Well, I'm just making the layout, it's not complete by any means. I was trying out values for elevations hoping to get some change in the layout. Thanks though. Changing the android:elevation to app:elevation worked for me, didn't know there was a difference between the two.